# Sort ArrayList by its properties

Tags: java, arraylist

I have class that looks like this:

```
public class Site
{
    String site_name;
        int site_number;
}
```

And I have an arraylist of sites

```
ArrayList<Site> SitesArr = new ArrayList<Site>();
```

How can I sort this SitesArr by site_number?

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/. check this for reference

Comment: You need comparable and comparators. Just read about these.

Comment: use comparator, it requires no change on your Site class,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options, first is to let your `Site` class implement the `Comparable` interface, than just implement `compareTo` in your class:

```
@Override 
public int compareTo(Site o) {
    Site s = (Site) o; 
    return this.site_number - s.site_number;
}
```

the second option is the create a new `Comparator` specific for the time that you want to sort your array:

```
new Comparator() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Site s1, Site s2) {
        return (s1.getSiteNumber() - s2.getSiteNumber());
    }
}
```

and then just use it when calling:

```
Collections.sort(SitesArr, comp);
```

I think that the first approach is the right one for this case

Answer (score 1):

use collection api such as Collection.sort(list);

Comment: Shuldn't be a comment?